# Spring methods being called twice

Tags: spring, jsf, servlets, primefaces

I have a Spring, PrimeFaces JSF application configured to load an application through a class that implements `WebApplicationInitializer` rather than `web.xml` (I do still have a bare `web.xml`) though.  The problem is on application start and basically throughout the whole application, methods are being called twice! Best explanation I found is possible double loading of one of the listeners. I don't see I'm doing that.  Attached is my `WebApplicationInitializer` class below.  I'm not sure what to else to provide to resolve my issue.  Even managed bean methods are being called twice.

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

    final CharacterEncodingFilter cf = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    cf.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    cf.setForceEncoding(true);

    servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());

    servletContext
            .addFilter(
                    "ShiroFilter",
                    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.IniShiroFilter.class)
            .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

    final WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));

    final ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("*.do");
}

private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
    final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.register(AppConfig.class);

    return context;
}
}
```

My `web.xml` has the standard definitions for faces and the following mapping:

```
   .....
 <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
   .....
 <!-- JSF Mapping -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When the application starts up, I see output from Spring that is also duplicated!

```
 2013-12-12T11:29:56.430-0500|INFO: [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext]  - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Dec 12 11:29:56 EST 2013]; root of context hierarchy

 2013-12-12T11:29:56.430-0500|INFO: [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext]  - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Dec 12 11:29:56 EST 2013]; root of context hierarchy

 2013-12-12T11:29:56.978-0500|INFO: [org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner]  - JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning

 2013-12-12T11:29:56.978-0500|INFO: [org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner]  - JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
```

How do I stop the duplicate calls?  Thanks.

**EDIT**
I'm using Log4j.  Here's my configuration:

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=[%c] %x - %m%n
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info, A1
log4j.logger.com.telus=info, A1
log4j.logger.org.springframework=info, A1
```

Using Spring 3.1.4.RELEASE.  PrimeFaces 4.0.  JSF 2.1.7. Deployed on Glassfish 3. Java 1.6.32.

Comment: That seems like a logger issue.

Comment: any pointers on what i can try? or any more information you need?

Comment: What logging framework are you using? Log4j, logback, other? Post your logger configuration.

Comment: I edited the post with Log4j configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to your `log4j.properties`

```
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate=false
log4j.additivity.com.telus=false
log4j.additivity.org.springframework=false
```

That should ensure that log messages aren't duplicated by the parent root logger.